# How to pass command line argument in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I learn C programming, and use Visual Studio Code.

I want to pass command line argument to the main function.

I don't know to pass argument to the main() funciton in Visual Studio Code.

I want to know the value of nArg, argv[0], argv[1'.

My code is as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

int nArg = argc;

char* arg1 = argv[0];
char* arg2 = argv[1];

printf("\nnumber of argument is %d", nArg);

printf("\n Arg1 is %s", arg1);
printf("\n Arg 2 is %s",arg2);



return 0;


}
```

Answer (score -1):

when you run the program,  just type the arguments after the program name (from the terminal)